# Calculating date difference in client side

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Please i need your assistance on how to differentiate between two dates like
(Start Date) 22/04/2017 - 24/04/2018 (End Date) with a result as 12months 2days. Should be done in client side. Any help pls

Comment: Similar question is already asked. you can check it for answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code to solve your problem.

```
var date1 = new Date("22/04/2017");
var date2 = new Date("24/04/2018");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

Comment: i just try it and the output is NAN

Comment: what is your question output??

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateDiffInDays = function(startDate, endDate) {

    var timeDiff = Date.parse(endDate) - Date.parse(startDate);
    return  daysDiff = Math.floor(timeDiff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}

console.log(dateDiffInDays("2018-05-01", "2018-06-23"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```js
var startDate = moment("22/04/2017", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var endDate = moment("24/04/2018", "DD/MM/YYYY");

var months = endDate.diff(startDate, 'months');
var days = endDate.subtract(months, 'months');
var diff = months + ' months ' + days.diff(startDate, 'days') + ' days';

$('#result').html(diff);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.12.0/moment.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```